# How does Twitter for iPhone bookmarklet work?

Tags: iphone, bookmarklet, mobile-safari

Twitter client (formerly Tweetie) allows you to define a bookmarklet in Safari that launches the app. I want to know which iPhone API allows you to register the protocol specifier (or whatever it's called) - in this case "tweetie:" - in order for this bookmarklet to work.

The instructions can be found [here](http://www.atebits.com/___?javascript:window.location=%27tweetie:%27+window.location) and the bookmarklet itself is below.

```
javascript:window.location='tweetie:'+window.location
```

Clicking the above bookmark is the same as typing in "tweetie:http://google.com" into the address bar. This is obviously supported on the OS/Browser level, much the same as `tel:` URIs. Am I correct in understanding that developers can add arbitrary URI protocol specifiers as a part of app installation?