# Can an app on mobile phone(iPhone) start another app?

Tags: iphone

E.g. When you download pdf on the browser (PC) hit starts the Adobe acrobat..similarly...can any app find another app is installed or not..and if its installed...can it start?

on iphone..when you click on a HTTP link from an app it starts browser automatically..similar..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is limited support for declaring custom URL schemes. Have a look at the [answer to a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919472/how-does-twitter-for-iphone-bookmarklet-work/2919507#2919507) I asked previously.